# Which data visualization library to choose?

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, data-visualization, ruby

Which data visualisation library for drawing interactive directed graphs do you recommend ? Preferably something that plays nicely with ruby on rails, allows styling, is open source, and offers different types of tree type graphs?

I narrowed it to a few but looking for recommendations:

- d3.js
- visjs
- arbor.js
- springy
- cytoscape

Examples of visualisations I'm looking for: Mostly trees with clickable/collapsible nodes)

http://visjs.org/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayoutMethods.html
http://arborjs.org/
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/11/02/us/politics/paths-to-the-white-house.html?_r=0
http://arborjs.org/

Another optional point I can add is that for my rails app, I use a hierarchical model that I would like to display in such a tree.

Comment: You are in danger of having this question closed as too broad (please read [ask]). I would suggest that you make it more specific by telling us which types of charts you need. Also, do you have any other functional requirements? And should it be [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget?

Comment: I specified already that I'm looking for directed graphs (or tree-type graphs). I also mentioned that I prefer open source and yes gratis would be good :)

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but 3 others already did. In an ideal world, they would have said why & you could have "improved" your question to their satisfaction. Can you think of anything to add? Maybe a link to non-Ruby product, for which you would like a Ruby equivalent? A picture of a tree-type graph?  I added the [tag:gratis] tag. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I added some details and links.

Comment: I **like** those examples - if only I could find something similar for Angualr JS ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the list of charting libraries mentioned in [Charting libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#supportedlibraries), which are used as charting engines in various contributed [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) modules (disclosure: I'm the original author of this page).

These are my personal favorites (also because they are used in the Drupal modules I (co-) maintain:

- PHP SVG Graph
- pChart
- D3

Up to you to further investigate which of these libraries might possibly be considered as a valid alternative in your case. While investigating, make sure to also consider the actual license (open source, commercial, etc) for those libraries.